# Google load balancer redirect IP address to specific port?

Tags: webserver, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I'm using google compute engine, and have set up a load balancer over an instance group. I have also reserved an ip address. Everything works just fine, if I access the specific port (8080), but if I just try to access the ip-address I get a '404 error'. I have also added a domain and have the same problem. `domain.com:8080` works but just `domain.com` gives a '404 error'.

Is the same host and path as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/827182/how-to-map-a-domain-name-to-a-load-balancer-in-google-cloud-platform/827186) (host: *, path: /*) guy enough? Or is there more configuration to be done. I can't seem to find this information in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup the load balancer frontend to listen to port 80 instead of 8080 and/or 443 for HTTPS (requires SSL certificate...)

Comment: Just read that port 80 is the default port for regular HTTP requests and tried it. Works perfectly, thanks!